# Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'EntityA_EntityBs' was not loaded because the type 'EntityB' is not available

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

### Background

I'm working on an application that uses Entity Framework to query a database from a third-party application. The database has a large number of tables and no foreign keys. I've mapped the relevant tables to entities using Entity Framework Fluent API.

#### Entities

```
namespace App.Entities
{
    public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual SalesOrder SalesOrder { get; set; }
        public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Lines { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Mappings

Note that the column and table name mappings are ommitted since I don't think they're relevant.

```
namespace App.Mappings
{
    public class TicketMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Ticket>
    {
        public TicketMap() {}
    }

    public class SalesOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SalesOrder>
    {
        public SalesOrderMap()
        {
            HasMany(t => t.Tickets)
                .WithRequired(t => t.SalesOrder)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.SalesOrderId);

            HasMany(t => t.Lines)
                .WithRequired(t => t.SalesOrder)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.SalesOrderId);
        }
    }
}
```

The entities and their mappings are correctly registered with Entity Framework.

### Problem

I'm receiving the following `MetadataException` when I try to run a query:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'App.SalesOrder_Tickets' was not loaded because the type 'App.Ticket' is not available.

Note that the namespace of `Ticket` shown in the above message is wrong. The entity class is actually in `App.Entities.Ticket`. However, I don't know if this is related to the problem or not.

### What I've Tried

1. Checking that the relationship appears to be correctly configured
2. Checking for duplicate classes in the model as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691043/the-relationship-was-not-loaded-because-the-type-is-not-available#comment30989243_20691043)
3. Checking that the entities are in the same namespace as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159497/238753)

Comment: [This CodePlex comment](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1536#PostedByLink1) may also be related to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was this pair of lines:

```
public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Lines { get; set; }
```

The element type of the second collection was supposed to be different to that of the first:

```
public virtual ICollection<TicketLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

Changing this fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but unfortunately don't spot any similar mistake. Stuck for hours!

Comment: Had a similar issue, duplicate/ambiguous properties was the root cause of mine. I had a base class implementation with PropertyA combined with an explicit interface on my POCO also with PropertyA it compiled because an explicit interface implementation doesn't hide existing properties. Valid C# but EF6 still failed... Renaming one property fixed it.

Comment: @josant so you can't have 2 collections of the same type?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message and the problem for me was that I had two different edmx models with Entities of the same name. I guess EF couldn't load some of the related entities and was giving a msg.

I solved deleting entities from one model (changing name would work as well I guess) and rebuilding the solution.